Reference needed: estimate of the second order derivatives
In $\mathbb{R}^d$ there is estimate (see  1.3, Chapter III of E.M.Stein' book Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions)
$$\left\|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)} \leq A_p \|\Delta f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}. $$
Similar estimate for bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $p=2$ may be found in the P.Grisvard' book Elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains, Theorem 3.1.2.1.
I'm looking for a reference for similar estimate in bounded domain with $p\ne 2$.

Without some assumption on $f$, this is clearly false, just take some $f$ with $\Delta f=0$.

For your estimate to hold on a bounded domain we clearly need $u$ to have zero boundary value, otherwise we can just take a (nonlinear) harmonic function to see that it cannot be true. So assume $u \in W_{0}^{2,p}(\Omega)$, where $1<p<\infty $ . Approximate $u$ in $ W^{2,p}$ norm by $ C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$ functions $u_m.$ Apply the inequality you found in Stein's book and take limits.

The desired estimate cannot hold on arbitrary domains, you need some boundary regularity. However, your answer does not need boundary regularity and, consequently, it should be invalid.
